# SearchView with history and custom suggestions

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a SearchView which will be used for searching through articles. In suggestions, SearchView should have some words found in articles and (below them) history (kind of like Google does it).
I found this tutorial: [adding recent query suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html), but I don't see a way to mix history results with custom results.​ Every explanation has one or the other.

Comment: see `SearchView#setSuggestionsAdapter(CursorAdapter adapter)` and use `android.database.MergeCursor` to merge 2 different data sources

Comment: If I do it like that, will I be able to add an icon ("history" icon) next to only those that came from history table?

Comment: sure,  it all depends what layout resource you will pass to SimpleCursorAdapter